# JPA .persist() doesn't save the data to the database while read works properly

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, dao

I have a Spring/JPA (with Hibernate as the JPA provider) with MySQL as the database provider.
I can't seem to be able to persist the data successfully even though I can read the data from the database.

I have searched through stackoverflow and most of the solutions dealt with decorating the save method with @Transactional (also the class). I verified the overall configuration but I can't seem to find out where I'm going wrong.

Here is my configuration

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/ p   ersistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="brPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/brDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.uhsarp.br.domain.Bill</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
              <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" /> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

spring application context

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

   <!-- JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
 <!--    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
         p:dataSource-ref="brDS"/>-->

         <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
 class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
     <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="brPersistenceUnit"/> 
  </bean> 
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

   <!-- Database LOB Handling -->
   <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />

   <!-- Read in DAOs from the JPA package -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.uhsarp.br.dao.framework.impl" />

   <!-- Transaction Config -->
   <bean id="transactionManager"
         class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
         p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
 <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

snippet of the DAO class

```
 @Repository("billDAO")
 @Transactional
 public class BillDAOImpl  implements BillDAO{
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
 public Bill save(Bill bill) {
     if (bill.getId() == null) {
                     em.persist(bill);

        return bill;
    } else {
        return em.merge(bill);
    }
 }
  }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense; if you're able to *read* the data from the database, it's been persisted.

Comment: The data I am able to read has not been persisted with JPA.

Comment: You doesn't seem to provide any DataSource for your EntityManagerFactory (neither in spring config nor in persistence.xml), so it is unclear how your code is connecting to underlying DB.

Comment: @SergeyMakarov The datasource is configured as a pool on the application server. I'm connecting to it via the jndi key 'brDS'. I have edited the persistence.xml to show it (I just missed including it in the original post). Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some insights on your setup: Does this happen in an JUnit test or with some specific frontend framework?

Comment: @mrak Here is the project repository on github https://github.com/billrive/billrive/tree/master/ I haven't written any unit tests yet but I'm in the process of writing a test to verify.. thanks. The instructions for setup are in the Readme.md file. Config help is in the "conf" folder

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to call your save method? Try to enable trace logs for both spring and hibernate, it will show what is being done step by step, including exact SQL sent to DB - should give you some clues on what the issue is.

Comment: I was briefly looking over your application; The only thing I found is the missing reference to transaction manager in <tx:annotation-driven/> (IMHO should be: <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>). But I'm not actively developing with Spring, so it's just a guess. You can still try to start a new transaction manually. If it fails (exception), than at least you know for sure, that there is a transaction manager. You can also try to call 'em.flush()' but this should really not be the final solution.

Comment: agree with mrak. I suspect transactions are not working at all and @transactional is ignored here or else post error message. Also post the actual code that you use to determine that this does not work! And if you have found the issue, please post the solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with JPA.

I had the data coming in from the Frontend (as JSON). Spring MVC did the data binding and created the 'Bill' object. Even though the object structure was formed without showing any errors, the ids were not being populated properly and that made JPA fail the .persist query.

The hibernate logs (show_sql in persistence.sql) did show that the transaction is being rolled back. But the hibernate logs are one of the worst logs I've ever come across (or I might be going blind). They are so verbose and hard to find the errors. I do however accept that I'm not a Hibernate veteran.

Also another challenge I faced is that I designed the database and objects separately and tried to validate the objects with the tables (Other ways are to let Hibernate generate the tables or let it generate the Entities from the tables). Although this is not a bad practice by any means, it is important to ensure that the design of the database and the Entities is proper and legit for everything to work properly. The application may build fine, JPA may validate the tables but that doesn't necessarily mean that your datamodel is legible. There are some hard experiences that I've learned through my initial adventure with JPA but I thank fellow devs from Stackoverflow for their wisdom in this process.